# how do i send an email through joomla

Tags: email, joomla

I have a system so folks can register for a class through my Joomla site (I believe it's 3.0). But from there, I would like to send folks an email filling variables from the registration. So something like:

```
Dear (name), thank you for registering for (class). 
This is to remind you your class is tomorrow, (date), at (place).
```

I believe for the registration, the system uses `authorize.net`

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `JFactory:getMailer` like suggested in the [*following post*](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/how-to-send-email-from-your-joomla-extension/). I'm copying here his code example (modified it a bit):

```
$subject = "Here is the subject of your message.";
$body = "Here is the body of your message.";
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$to = $user->email;
$from = array("me@mydomain.com", "Brian Edgerton");

# Invoke JMail Class
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

# Set sender array so that my name will show up neatly in your inbox
$mailer->setSender($from);

# Add a recipient -- this can be a single address (string) or an array of addresses
$mailer->addRecipient($to);

$mailer->setSubject($subject);
$mailer->setBody($body);

# If you would like to send as HTML, include this line; otherwise, leave it out
$mailer->isHTML();

# Send once you have set all of your options
$mailer->send();
```

That's all there is to it for sending a simple email. If you would like to add carbon copy recipients, include the following before sending the email:

```
# Add a blind carbon copy
$mailer->addBCC("blindcopy@yourdomain.com");
```

Another alternative is using `JMail::sendMail`: http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JMail::sendMail

Comment: If you send HTML mail, remember to set the altBody or gmail will treat it as spam

Comment: Can you please explain more I'm trying to use your code example $subject you didn't declare $subject; can you please help me and explain more I'm trying your code on localhost http://127.0.0.1

Comment: @wbdevlop you're right it wasn't declared properly, thanks. I fixed it (the answer was edited respectively).

Comment: @alfasin I'm using localhost (127.0.0.1 ) I tried your code but emails not send

Comment: @alfasin which extension ?

Comment: @wbdevlop sorry disregard my previous comment, I wrote this answer a long time ago and it's no longer fresh in my head :) I guess that you'll have to debug it and see where it fails: wrap everything with try / catch, add log-prints, use a debugger and etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Fetch the Mail Object:**

```
`$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();`
```

Set a Sender

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();  
$recipient = $user->email;    
$mailer->addRecipient($recipient);    
$mailer->setSender($sender);
```

Recipient

```
   $user = JFactory::getUser();    
   $recipient = $user->email;    
   $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);
```

Create the Mail

```
   $body   = 'Body Text';    
   $mailer->isHtml(true);    
   $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';    
   $mailer->setBody($body);
```

Sending the Mail

```
$send = $mailer->Send();   
if ( $send !== true ) {    
    echo 'Error sending email: ';    
} else {    
    echo 'Mail sent';    
}
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions